# can not connect to FTPS (explicit) server with java?

Tags: java, ssl, ftps, apache-commons-net

I use this code to connect to ftps with explicit encryption

```
String host = "10.21.13.66";
int port = 21;
String username = "user";
String password = "pass";
 try {
FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient("ssl",false);
ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new  PrintWriter(System.out)));
ftpClient.connect(host, port);
int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {

// Login
(ftpClient.login(username, password)) 
}
} catch (IOException ioe) {
System.out.println("FTP client received network error");
}
```

when I try to connect to my own ftps it returns this error: 431 No security resource for TLS/SSL encryption, probably there is no selected SSL certificate

any help would be appreciated;

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the auth on ftps client using below code after object is constructed:

ftpClient.setAuthValue("TLS");

Comment: the same exception oucured

Comment: The problem was with creating server, I didnt set certificate for it, cause I though certificate is nessecary just for implicit connection, but I was wrong